# How to create mini-batches of predefined sizes from a sparse 2D matrix in Python?

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix, mini-batch

I have a sparse 2D matrix saved on a disk (`.npz` extension) that I've created in preprocessing step with `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`. It is a long sequence of piano-roll (a numerical form of MIDI representation) format 1-channel image. I cannot convert whole matrix to dense representation - it will not fit in my memory.

How do I create mini-batches with predefined sizes from the sparse matrix?

I've tried converting CSR representation to COO and creating batches of data from it.

```py
sparse_matrix = sc.sparse.load_npz(file_name)
coo_matrix = sparse_matrix.tocoo()
for batch_index in range(num_batches):
    start_index = batch_index * num_samples
    end_index = (batch_index + 1) * num_samples

    start_index = batch_index * num_samples
    end_index = (batch_index + 1) * num_samples

    batch_data = coo_matrix.data[start_index:end_index]
    batch_row = coo_matrix.row[start_index:end_index]
    batch_col = coo_matrix.col[start_index:end_index]

    batch_sparse_matrix = scipy.sparse.coo_matrix(
        (batch_data, (batch_row, batch_col)),
        shape=(batch_size, image_width*image_height)
    )
```

but I got errors like: `row index exceeds matrix dimensions` which means I have too much data for the shape I defined. The row and col index is outside of shape boundaries.

I've tried something like this, to get the right amount of data, but it's very slow.

```py
non_zero_indices = np.where((co_matrix.row >= start_index) & (co_matrix.row < end_index))[0]

start_index = non_zero_indices[0]
end_index = non_zero_indices[-1] + 1
```

Comment: Do you understand the `indptr`, `indices` and `data` attributes of a `csr`?  `indptr` can be used index rows.  But you can also use indexing  `M[10:100]` returns a 90 row slice (copy) of `M`.  row indexing is relatively efficent. 
 https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix

Comment: Yep, that worked. CSR was more suitable for this problem. This is my solution `rows_to_extract = np.arange(start_index, end_index); batch_sparse_matrix = self.sparse_matrix[rows_to_extract, :]`