# Reading and Processing Large Sparse Matrix in Batches using Python

Tags: matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a large sparse matrix stored in a file, and I need to process it in batches due to memory limitations. I'm looking for an efficient way to read and process consecutive parts of the sparse matrix without loading the entire file into memory at once.

I have tried using the `scipy.sparse` module in Python to handle the sparse matrix. However, the available functions like `scipy.sparse.load_npz()` load the entire matrix into memory, which is not feasible for my case.

Here is an example of my current code:

```py
class SparseDataLoader:
    def __init__(self, file_name, batch_size, image_width, image_height):
        self.sparse_matrix = sc.sparse.load_npz(file_name)
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.image_width = image_width
        self.image_height = image_height
        self.num_batches = self.sparse_matrix.shape[0] // batch_size

    def __iter__(self):
        for batch_index in range(self.num_batches):
            start_index = batch_index * self.image_width * self.batch_size
            end_index = (batch_index + 1) * self.image_width * self.batch_size

            rows_to_extract = np.arange(start_index, end_index)
            batch_sparse_matrix = self.sparse_matrix[rows_to_extract, :]

            batch_dense_matrix = batch_sparse_matrix.toarray()
            batch_images = batch_dense_matrix.reshape(self.batch_size, self.image_width, self.image_height, 1)
            batch_images = np.transpose(batch_images, (0, 2, 1, 3))
            yield batch_images
```

Is there a way to modify this code to read and process only a part of the sparse matrix at a time? I want to load consecutive parts of the matrix, create batches of dense matrices, and avoid loading the entire file into memory.

I have looked into the `scipy.sparse` module, but I couldn't find a function that allows reading specific rows or loading the matrix in parts. Is there a more efficient approach or a different library that can handle this scenario?

Any suggestions or guidance on how to efficiently read and process a large sparse matrix in batches would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Here is the link to the question in which I am creating the dataset: [How to create mini-batches of predefined sizes from a sparse 2D matrix in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76258950/how-to-create-mini-batches-of-predefined-sizes-from-a-sparse-2d-matrix-in-python?noredirect=1#comment134479726_76258950)

Comment: Do you control the format of the file? You likely need to depart from NPZ to be able to do this efficiently.

Comment: Yes, I create this file in another script. But this seems like a reasonable format since values are stored row-wise and I need to load batches of rows as well.

Answer (score 0):

I remembered helping with a similar question about processing a CSC matrix in batches.  So I looked up your history, etc.  You should provide that kind of link in the question, and not depend on my memories.

Look at the code for `save_npz` and `load_npz`. That just uses the `np.savez` function to write the key attributes of your matrix to a file.  For CSC that means the zip archive has 4 files - shape, data, indices, indptr.  On load, it gets those arrays and then does a straight forward matrix creation:

```
M = sparse.csc_matrix((data, indices, indptr), shape)
```

From that you can proceed with the batches as in the previous question.

So `save/load_npz` just uses existing sparse and numpy functions.  There's no added 'batch' or partial load tools.

People have asked about partial loads of `npy` array, but I don't think anyone has suggested a good method.  It wouldn't be impossible but you have to know how the `npy` is stored.

In this case you could open the `npz` archive directly, and load the 4 arrays yourself, and skip the 'make csc' step.  Obviously you can't do anything meaningful with the data/indices arrays until you have the 'column' boundaries defined in the `indptr`.

In short, you'd have to know a lot about `np.savez/load` to bypass the `sparse.load_npz` step.